# TapLink's architecture

Tags: passwords, salt

Can anyone describe how [Taplink](http://taplink.co)'s proposed architecture would look like? I heard a very high-level pitch but found no detailed technical explanation.

This is a proposed architecture to harden passwords with a scheme that secures them against hash leaks and offline attacks. But published details appear to be scarce.

Comment: They talk about it in more detail in [their Passwords^12 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i7l8MiLGEg). Have you checked it out? Perhaps you could describe what you know/have read already in the question.

Comment: Have you contacted them?

Comment: Whitepaper coming on website soon ( https://twitter.com/0xF2/status/753207636221370368 ). I thought they got started in 2012?

Comment: There is also [a BSides talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuX_RFV1zr8).